# How can I tar gz files with file name date range?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to make a tar.gz file which compresses multiple files, selected by exact date range which composes the name of the files.
for example, file names are

```
system.2020-01-21.log
system.2020-01-22.log
system.2020-01-24.log
...
```

I want to set the exact date range for selecting files to be compressed. The output file will be

```
system.2020-01-20-2020-02-20.log.tar.gz
```

I tried this one below.

```
LAST_LOG_FILES=`find $LOG_HOME/system*.log -newerBt $LAST_LOG_Y_M_D ! -newerBt $CURR_LOG_Y_M_D`
LOG_ZIP="$LOG_HOME/stage.$LAST_LOG_Y_M_D-$CURR_LOG_Y_M_D.log.tar.gz"
tar -czf $LOG_ZIP $LAST_LOG_FILES
```

However, this throws error below.

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive. Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

I think this mean the command doesn't set file name range, resulting in empty archive.

If you know better command to do this operation, would you inform me? 
I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: What does `echo "$LAST_LOG_FILES"` show?

Comment: `-newerBt` doesn't use the date in the filename, it uses the inode creation time of the file.

Comment: @Barmar Yes that was the problem. I need to use the name of the file, not the birthday of the file. I could solve the problem, helped by the answer below. I appreciate your help too. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select the log file to be compressed based on the filenames,
you will need to compare the filenames one by one.
Would you please try the following:

```
start="2020-01-20"
end="2020-02-20"
log_home="log"          # assign to your LOG_HOME

for f in "$log_home"/system.*.log; do
    base=${f##*/}       # strip leading directory name
    if [[ $base > system.$start.log && $base < system.$end.log || $base = system
.$start.log || $base = system.$end.log ]]; then
                        # if start <= base <= end
        files+=("$f")   # then add the file to the list to compress
    fi
done

if (( ${#files[@]} )); then
                        # if the list of the files is not empty
    log_zip="$log_home/system.$start-$end.log.tar.gz"
    tar -czf "$log_zip" "${files[@]}"
fi
```

- The variable `${#files[@]}` represents the number of elements in the
  array `files`. The condition test avoids the case the list is empty.
- The expression `"${files[@]}"` expands the elements of the array
  as: "system.2020-01-21.log" "system.2020-01-22.log" ...

Comment: This works perfectly well! I appreciate your help. At the first time, the last "if" part is kind of complicated code for me, but I finally figured out why the code works. I appreciate again :)

Comment: @GaramChoi thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. I've added a small explanation about the "if" part. Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate it again! For just in case, I want to tell that I didn't mean I evaluated your code. I just wanted to say that at least I tried to fully understand the code, not just copy and paste your help. Of course your code is written well to understand also for newbie like me. Have a good day :)

Comment: @GaramChoi okay, understood. I salute your effort and enthusiasm!